# Faster alternative to apache airflow for workflows with many tasks

Tags: python, celery, workflow, etl, airflow

I currently use Apache Airflow for running data aggregation and ETL workflows. My workflows are fairly complex with one workflow having 15-20 tasks and have branches. I can combine them but doing so would negate the features like retry, execution timers that I use. Airflow works well except that it is quite slow with so many tasks. It takes lot of time between tasks.

Is there an alternative which can execute the tasks faster without gaps in between tasks? I also would like to minimize the effort needed to switch over if possible.

Comment: You can build ANY workflow with Celery.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend [Temporal Workflow](https://temporal.io/). It has more developer friendly programming model and scales to orders of magnitude larger use cases. It also already used for multiple latency sensitive applications at many companies.

*Disclaimer*: I'm the tech lead of the Temporal project and the Co-founder/CEO of the associated company.

Comment: Python library is under active development: https://github.com/firdaus/cadence-python

Comment: I suggest you to mention the fact that you are the CEO of the company as a disclaimer.

Comment: Good point. Updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you try out Dataplane. It is an Airflow alternative written in Golang to achieve super fast performance and can scale with far less resources. It has a built in Python code editor with a drag and drop data pipeline builder. It also has segregated environments so you can build your route to live or different data domains to construct a data mesh. It is totally free to use.

Here is the link: https://github.com/dataplane-app/dataplane

*Disclaimer*: I am part of the community that actively contributes towards Dataplane.

Comment: You can find Dataplane here: https://github.com/dataplane-app/dataplane